# Blackberry and Iphone Video format transcoding from WMV

Tags: iphone, blackberry, video, wmv, transcoding

I need to be able to deploy a video to both Iphone and Blackberry platform,
Is there a shared format that they both can play?
The deployment is via email as attachment.

This can save me some time with testing, if someone had the same problem and can offer input i would help me a bunch and I would like some input about the trans-coding process, my client doesn't care if he needs to pay a license free to use a component. If someone wrote code that converts to this joint format using an external library of command line tool, I would be happy to learn which tool or library you used.

I am converting from WMV.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you considered that sending videos via e-mail generally is a bad idea? Many mail servers will reject large attachments, many users have severely restricted inbox sizes (my work one is only 50 MB), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to get .mp4 (h264 encoded) video working on iOS, Android, and BlackBerry. It's the closest thing to a mobile standard as far as I'm aware.

Sending videos to people via e-mail is a pretty bad delivery method, though.